# mySql Distinct - group by issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out the most purchased products but to only count distinct users ids. Basically my client wants to stop duplicate purchases from the same user, so that they can't affect the chart/best sellers.
I need to count all order_items for that product, using only Distinct users ids. Currently the results are counting all order_items so the Distinct isn't working.

Any help and I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT * 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT 
              order_item_meta_3.meta_value as distinct_user_order_items_id,
              order_item_meta_2.meta_value as product_id,
              SUM( order_item_meta.meta_value ) as item_quantity
           FROM
              wp_woocommerce_order_items as order_items
                 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta
                    ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
                 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta_2
                    ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta_2.order_item_id
                 LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta_3
                    ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta_3.order_item_id 
                 LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS posts 
                    ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
                    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel 
                       ON posts.ID = rel.object_ID
                    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tax 
                       USING( term_taxonomy_id )
                    LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS term 
                       USING( term_id )
           WHERE
                  posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
              AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
              AND tax.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
              AND term.slug IN ('completed','processing','on-hold')
              AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
              AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_qty'
              AND order_item_meta_2.meta_key = '_product_id'
              AND order_item_meta_3.meta_key = '_user_id'
           GROUP BY
              order_item_meta_2.meta_value
           ORDER BY
              item_quantity DESC ) as order_table, 
      wp_posts 
         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as mk1
            ON wp_posts.ID = mk1.post_id
         LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as mk2
            ON wp_posts.ID = mk2.post_id
   WHERE
          order_table.product_id = wp_posts.ID
      AND wp_posts.ID = mk1.post_id
      AND mk1.meta_key = 'is_album' 
      AND mk1.meta_value = 0
      AND mk2.meta_key = '_price' 
      AND mk2.meta_value = 0
```

Comment: You know DISTINCT acts on all the columns in the SELECT, right?

Comment: add order_item_meta_3.meta_value to group by in inner select... remove distinct.

Comment: Most of these are (optimized as) INNER JOINs! Was that your intention?

Comment: You can't mix conventions on table joins... `ORDER BY
        item_quantity DESC ) as order_table , wp_posts ` this really runs this way?

Comment: xQbert, I've removed distinct and grouped by order_item_meta_3.meta_value but the item_quantity is still wrong, its 2 when it should be 1.

Comment: Can you please clarify purchased products per user.  If person A buys 10 of product "X" and person B buys 1, you only want that counted product "X" as sold to 2 distinct people regardless of the overall 11 quantity?  Or preventing things like Person "A" buys 10 separate times, and person B buys 1 of same item "X" and looking like it was bought 11 times sold.  Either way, I THINK you want person A bought product X no matter how many orders it appeared on.  A may have bought 50 other products, each counted ONCE for that person.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Also, SQL clarification.  Your two "USING" instances of the join.  Confirm which tables they are being joined to as it appears ambiguous.  Also, all your left-joins that you ultimately include in the WHERE clause is changing them into INNER JOINs. Is that intentional, or by mistake.

Comment: Yes, Person A and B you've described in correct. No matter how many times Person A buys a certain product, it will be counted as one towards the chart. My client is trying to stop users buy their own records multiple times and affecting the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you need to do the sum outside the group by.  you have to materialize the distinct set first then aggregate it...

so change first few lines to...

```
SELECT distinct_user_order_items_Id, product_Id, sum(item_Quantity) as item_Quantity
FROM (
SELECT
        order_item_meta_3.meta_value as distinct_user_order_items_id,
        order_item_meta_2.meta_value as product_id,
        order_item_meta.meta_value as item_quantity
```

Comment: I'm only getting one row now. I need it to group by product_id so that I can see how many times that product has been sold and output the chart. Apologies if I'm not explaining it clearly.


Here is the updated query http://pastebin.com/bx9nMB9v